# How do I properly configure nginx for domain name access?

Tags: nginx

There is such a config

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 18.157.238.183 team-mate.app www.team-mate.app;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
    location /static/ {
    root /app;
    }
}
```

The website opens by ip address

```
18.157.238.183:8000
```

but not the domain name

Hosting has the following configuration (it has been a few days since A was added)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dig team-mate.app` shows two A records (I guess the second one is the "Parked" one from your screenshot):

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
team-mate.app.      443 IN  A   18.157.238.183
team-mate.app.      443 IN  A   34.102.136.180
```

The second one obviously doesn't reach your server, and is at the moment not listening to port 8000.

If you want to test it locally, you can add an entry in `/etc/hosts` with the `18.157.238.183` IP so you are sure to hit this, and when you are ready to go live, you should change the DNS to have a single A record (or run your nginx also at the second IP), otherwise 50% of the requests will fail.

Comment: I just tested it by adding `18.157.238.183 team-mate.app` to my `/etc/hosts` and indeed it works: `curl -o /dev/null http://team-mate.app:8000/` succeeds. That means your nginx configuration works, but you need to fix the DNS issue I pointed out above.

Comment: I've remove default A record. The only thing left is  `team-mate.app.  581 IN A 18.157.238.183` . But `team-mate.app:8000` still unavailable.

Comment: The server side works (e.g. the curl command I pasted above succeeds), the problem comes from the browsers that are very eager (and that's a good thing actually) to forward everything to https. I tried setting in firefox for testing in about:config the value of `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` to False and I can go to `http://team-mate.app:8000` and your page shows up normally. The correct solution is of course to set up SSL and accept HTTPS connections instead.

Comment: Great advice. Checked curl access and it's working. Thanks for the help!